# Play 2.5 type mismatch Session type

Tags: scala, playframework, play-authenticate, deadbolt-2

Using [deadbolt2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2) I have the following controller function implementation:

```
def restricted: Action = deadbolt.Restrict(List(Array(USER_ROLE)))() { request =>
  Future {
    val localUser = userProvider.getUser(request.session) // <<< expects a play.mvc.Http.Session
    Ok(views.html.restricted(userProvider, localUser))
  }
}
```

but it results in the following compiler error:

```
[error] /home/bravegag/code/play-authenticate-usage-scala/app/controllers/Application.scala:26: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.mvc.Session
[error]  required: play.mvc.Http.Session
[error]       val localUser = userProvider.getUser(request.session)
[error]                                                    ^
```

Basically the current `request` is giving me a `play.api.mvc.Session` but the library I depend on ([play-authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate)) is expecting a `play.mvc.Http.Session`. Is there a way to convert between the two? or another way to get hold of the needed Http one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to convert from `play.api.mvc.Session` to `play.mvc.Http.Session`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions

val session : Http.Session = 
    new Http.Session(JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(request.session.data))
```

thouhg I will have to keep redoing this everywhere ... or write an implicit conversion Helper object.

**UPDATE** Defined my own implicit conversion helper:

```
package utils

import scala.collection.JavaConversions

object PlayConversions {
  /**
    * Returns the result conversion from a play.api.mvc.Session to a play.mvc.Http.Session
    * @param session play.api.mvc.Session instance
    * @return the result conversion from a play.api.mvc.Session to a play.mvc.Http.Session
    */
  implicit def toHttpSession(session: play.api.mvc.Session) = new play.mvc.Http.Session(JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(session.data))
}
```

**UPDATE** Actually this is the Play institutional/preferred way to do it:

```
import play.core.j.JavaHelpers

val context = JavaHelpers.createJavaContext(request)
// and now access the Java Http.Session
context.session
```